# How to filter full name string properly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So i have an array of objects which I want to filter with a search input.

```
const people = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe',
  }
];
```

I made this function to take a list and a search value so It could return filtered list.

```
const filterList = (list, searchValue) => {
  let filtered = list.filter(item => {
    
    let fullName = item.firstName.toLowerCase() + item.lastName.toLowerCase()
    let trimmedSearchValue = searchValue.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    
    return fullName.includes(trimmedSearchValue.toLowerCase())
  })
  return filtered
}
```

Filtering works when I call it like this

```
console.log(filterList(people, 'john'))
// returns { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
console.log(filterList(people, 'jane'))
// returns { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"} 
console.log(filterList(people, 'doe'))
// returns both objects [
// { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"},
// { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"} 
//  ]
```

But when I call it like this I get empty array as a result

```
console.log(filterList(people, 'doe j'))
//returns empty array [], expected to get back both objects

console.log(filterList(people, 'doe john'))
//returns empty array [], expected to get {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
```

I think I am not correctly comparing fullName with searchValue but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: looks like you're concatenating first+last name...did you mean to concatenate the opposite order, last+first?

Comment: if you send `doe john`, it becomes `trimmedSearchValue = "doejohn"` and `fullName = "johndoe"` which doesn't matches any, that's why returning empty result. You need to reverse the `fullName` as well. try `firstname + lastname` and `lastname + firstname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare with the lastName+firstName as well:

```js
const filterList = (list, searchValue) => {
  return list.filter(item => {
    const fullName = `${item.firstName}${item.lastName}`.toLowerCase();
    const reversedFullName = `${item.lastName}${item.firstName}`.toLowerCase();
    const trimmedSearchValue = searchValue.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    return fullName.includes(trimmedSearchValue) || reversedFullName.includes(trimmedSearchValue);
  });
}

const people = [
  { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' }
];

console.log(filterList(people, 'doe j'));
console.log(filterList(people, 'doe john'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
const people = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe',
  }
];

const filterList = (list, searchValue) => {
  let filtered = list.filter(item => {
    const arr = searchValue.split(' ');
    return arr.some(el => item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(el) || item.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(el));
  })
  return filtered
}

console.log(filterList(people, 'doe j'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job too:

```js
const people = [{firstName: 'John',lastName: 'Doe'},
                {firstName: 'Jane',lastName: 'Doe'}];
function find(arr,pat){
 let pa=pat.trim().replace(/ +/g," ").split(" ")
           .map(p=>new RegExp(p,"i"));
 return arr.filter(n=>{
  let name=n.firstName+" "+n.lastName;
  return pa.every(p=>p.test(name))
 })
}

["doe j","john","jan do"].forEach(t=>  // test cases ...
  console.log(find(people,t))
)
```